# Task Manager Frontend table Not Displaying

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm not a coder, I found this code online where i sounds helpful to my office task, The task fields are recording in the Google sheets when I add a task but it's not displaying in the front end as I click "Add a Task" button. This table works like crud operations, I did some modiificatiosn but it didn't go well as I thought. Please could you help me on this.

[Google Sheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qftB7S9RJyG-SrUI0I2PJgVQH3DtyqLsyISZjFxUk7c/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

code.gs

```
    function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index.html")
    .setTitle("Google Sheets Web App")
    .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}


// Get the sheet data
function getSheetData() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  return data;
}

// Add a new task to the sheet
function addTaskToSheet(data) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const jobId = generateJobId();
  const newRow = [jobId, data.task, data.assigned, data.priority, data.date, data.folderLink];
  sheet.appendRow(newRow);
}

// Update a task in the sheet
function updateTaskInSheet(index, data) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const row = sheet.getRange(index + 1, 1, 1, 6); // Add 1 to the index to account for the header row
  row.setValues([data]);
}

// Delete a task from the sheet
function deleteTaskFromSheet(index) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sheet.deleteRow(index + 1); // Add 1 to the index to account for the header row
}

// Generate a JobID
function generateJobId() {
  return Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5).toUpperCase();
}
```

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Task Manager</h1>
      <form id="taskForm">
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col">
            <label for="task">Task:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="task" name="task" required>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <label for="assigned">Assigned:</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="assigned" name="assigned">
              <option value="Person A">Person A</option>
              <option value="Person B">Person B</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <label for="priority">Priority:</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="priority" name="priority">
              <option value="High">High</option>
              <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
              <option value="Low">Low</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <label for="date">Date:</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" value="" required>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <label for="folderLink">Folder Link:</label>
            <input type="url" class="form-control" id="folderLink" name="folderLink" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Add Task</button>
      </form>
      <hr>
      <h2>Tasks</h2>
      <table class="table" id="tasksTable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>JobID</th>
            <th>Task</th>
            <th>Assigned</th>
            <th>Priority</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Folder Link</th>
            <th>Update</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <!-- Table content will be added dynamically -->
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        // Load tasks from Google Sheets
        loadTasks();

        // Initialize the date input with today's date
        $("#date").val(new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10));

        // Handle form submission
        $("#taskForm").on("submit", function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          addTask();
        });
      });

      // Load tasks from Google Sheets
                 function loadTasks() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(renderTasks).getSheetData();
      }

      // Render tasks in the table
      function renderTasks(tasks) {
        $("#tasksTable tbody").empty();
        tasks.forEach((task, index) => {
          if (index === 0) return; // Skip header row
          const row = $("<tr></tr>");
          task.forEach((cell, cellIndex) => {
            if (cellIndex === 5) {
              row.append(`<td><a href="${cell}" target="_blank">Open Folder</a></td>`);
            } else {
              row.append(`<td>${cell}</td>`);
            }
          });

          // Add edit and delete buttons
          row.append(`
            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info" onclick="editTask(${index})">Edit</button>
              <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="deleteTask(${index})">Delete</button>
            </td>
          `);

          $("#tasksTable tbody").append(row);
        });
      }

    // Add a new task
function addTask() {
  const formData = $("#taskForm").serializeArray().reduce((obj, item) => {
    obj[item.name] = item.value;
    return obj;
  }, {});

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(() => {
    loadTasks();
    $("#taskForm").trigger("reset");
    $("#date").val(new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10));
  }).addTaskToSheet(formData);
}

      // Edit task
      function editTask(index) {
        // Add your edit task logic here
        // You can access the row data using the index parameter
        // and update it using the 'updateTask' function (defined in the next step)
      }

      // Update task
      function updateTask(index, updatedData) {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(loadTasks).updateTaskInSheet(index, updatedData);
      }

      // Delete task
      function deleteTask(index) {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(loadTasks).deleteTaskFromSheet(index);
      }

// Render tasks in the table
function renderTasks(tasks) {
  $("#tasksTable tbody").empty();
  if (!tasks || tasks.length === 0) {
    return;
  }
  tasks.slice(1).forEach((task, index) => { // Start from the second row to skip the header row
    const row = $("<tr></tr>");
    task.forEach((cell, cellIndex) => {
      if (cellIndex === 5) {
        const cellValue = cell ? cell : ""; // Check for null value
        row.append(`<td><a href="${cellValue}" target="_blank">Open Folder</a></td>`);
      } else {
        const cellValue = cell ? cell : ""; // Check for null value
        row.append(`<td>${cellValue}</td>`);
      }
    });

    // Add edit and delete buttons
    row.append(`
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info" onclick="editTask(${index + 1})">Edit</button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="deleteTask(${index + 1})">Delete</button>
      </td>
    `);

    $("#tasksTable tbody").append(row);
  });
}


function loadTasks() {
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler((tasks) => {
      renderTasks(tasks);
    })
    .getSheetData();
}
$(document).ready(loadTasks);


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your browser, press F12 and see if there are any red boxes displaying errors when you open your Web App, as well as when you click the button; post any screenshots or paste any errors you see.

Comment: hi @NEWAZA I've edited the post F12 error messages. Please view.

Comment: Tanaike-sama has answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your Javascript, there are 2 `renderTasks`. And also, there are 2 `loadTasks()`.
- From your Spreadsheet, in your Spreadsheet, the date object is included in column "E". In this case, when `getValues` is used, `null` is returned from `getSheetData()`.
- And, you want to create `editTask` function. At that time, you want `The job ID should remain the same (Job ID is only for referral purpose)`.

I thought that the reason for your current issue is due to the above points. When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

##### Google Apps Script:

Please modify `getSheetData()` and `updateTaskInSheet(index, data)` as follows.

```js
function getSheetData() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  return data;
}

function updateTaskInSheet(index, data) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const row = sheet.getRange(index + 1, 2, 1, 5);
  row.setValues([data]);
}
```

##### HTML & Javascript:

Please modify Javascript as follows.

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Load tasks from Google Sheets
  loadTasks();

  // Initialize the date input with today's date
  $("#date").val(new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10));

  // Handle form submission
  $("#taskForm").on("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    addTask();
  });
});

// Load tasks from Google Sheets
function loadTasks() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(renderTasks).getSheetData();
}

function renderTasks(tasks) {
  $("#tasksTable tbody").empty();
  if (!tasks || tasks.length === 0) {
    return;
  }
  tasks.slice(1).forEach((task, index) => { // Start from the second row to skip the header row
    const row = $("<tr></tr>");
    task.forEach((cell, cellIndex) => {
      if (cellIndex === 5) {
        const cellValue = cell ? cell : ""; // Check for null value
        row.append(`<td><a href="${cellValue}" target="_blank">Open Folder</a></td>`);
      } else {
        const cellValue = cell ? cell : ""; // Check for null value
        row.append(`<td>${cellValue}</td>`);
      }
    });

    // Add edit and delete buttons
    row.append(`
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info" onclick="editTask(${index + 1})">Edit</button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="deleteTask(${index + 1})">Delete</button>
      </td>
    `);

    $("#tasksTable tbody").append(row);
  });
}

// Add a new task
function addTask() {
  const formData = $("#taskForm").serializeArray().reduce((obj, item) => {
    obj[item.name] = item.value;
    return obj;
  }, {});

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(() => {
    loadTasks();
    $("#taskForm").trigger("reset");
    $("#date").val(new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10));
  }).addTaskToSheet(formData);
}

// Update task
function editTask(index, updatedData) {
  const formData = $("#taskForm").serializeArray().map(({value}) => value);
  if (!formData[0] || !formData[4]) {
    alert("When you edit task, please input the above input tags and click 'Edit' button.");
    return;
  }
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(loadTasks).updateTaskInSheet(index, formData);
}

// Delete task
function deleteTask(index) {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(loadTasks).deleteTaskFromSheet(index);
}
</script>
```

- When your Web Apps is opened by reflecting this modified script, you can see the task list in the HTML.
- And, after you input the values to the input tags and click "Edit" button, the value is updated.

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### Reference:

- [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252588/discussion-on-answer-by-tanaike-task-manager-frontend-table-not-displaying); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.